# How to open local file links with special characters?

Tags: html, firefox

I have an intranet here where I want to link to some local files on a network share.
The Path to the files has special characters (mutated vowel, e.g. "äöü").
My href-links look like the following:

```
href="file:///\\SERVER\share\path\für alle\example.pdf"
```

The link does work in IE, and also if I open it in Firefox as a new Tab. But it doesn't work if I simply click on it. Instead of the document, my local folder "My documents" opens.

Do I make something wrong? Or is this a Bug in Firefox? (using Firefox 32.0.1)

PS:
for your information: I have allowed the local file links in Firefox in "about:config" with the following entries:

```
capability.policy.policynames: localfilelinks
capability.policy.localfilelinks.checkloaduri.enabled: allAccess
capability.policy.localfilelinks.sites: http://intranet
```

Comment: could it be, that 'my documents' is the default application? have you tried rightclick --> open with firefox?

Comment: I don't think, this is the problem. Because it works, when I open the link as new tab (middle mouse button, or STRG + left mouse button). Also this problem affects different file types (images, .docx, .pdf, ...). When I right click one of the PDF files and open with firefox, then it opens in Firefox.

Comment: You could also escape all "special" characters when writing url:s, in your case it would look like this:
file%3A%2F%2F%2F%5C%5CSERVER%5Cshare%5Cpath%5Cf%C3%BCr%20alle%5Cexample.pdf or maybee just: file:///\\SERVER\share\path\f%C3%BCr%20alle\example.pdf

Comment: I tried to escape the whole string, but this also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried different computers now. Obviously, this error only appears on my own computer.
I have created a new firefox profile, this solved the problem. So my profile seems to be corrupted or maybe I have a problematic setting.